# Stuck in Order by more then one

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, get-posts

I want to orderby post by 2 custom fields and alphabetical
here is my code

```
'meta_query'    => array(
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'awards' => array(
            'key'       => 'awards',
            'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'points' => array(
            'key'       => 'points',
            'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
),
'orderby' => array(

    'awards'       => 'desc',
    'points'     => 'desc',
),
```

So if the awards are same so it will order by points but if the points will same also so it will orber by alphabetical.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the unnecessary array involved around clauses. The correct code is

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'awards_clause'   => array( // clause
        'key'     => 'awards',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ),
    'points_clause'   => array( // clause
        'key'     => 'points',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ),
),
'orderby'    => array(
    'awards_clause' => 'DESC',
    'points_clause' => 'DESC',
),
```